# Angularjs - force the browser to return to a different location via "back button"

Tags: angularjs, redirect, navigation, location, history

I am on #loc1. On button click I want to go to #loc3 from #loc1, in such a way that doing back from #loc3 should take me to #loc2. Is that possible in Angularjs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried *.history.back()?

Comment: yes, it takes u back to the last visited link. In fact what I want to do is something like this... $location.path('#loc2').replace(); $scope.apply(); $location.path('#loc3');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there does not exist any method to achieve this. I solved it by forcing the browser to #loc2 from #loc1. From #loc2 I forced it to #loc3, so that the back button takes it back to #loc2.

Answer (score 1):

You can force to go backward without taking in consideration **.back()** state.

Example:(set for each location to go backward with 1 route)

```
$location.path('/yourLocation').replace();
```

Comment: Consider I am on the new employee page. I want to select the department. I do not find the department I m looking for. So I have to go to add department page. What I want to do at this point is first store the information of the employee in HTML storage, generate a temporary url for that and than go to the department page. From there when I say back, the browser should land up on the temporary generated url. I cannot hard code to return to a particular page because I don't know from where the add department page was called. Am I making sense? Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Do let me know if there is any better way of doing this in angularjs.

Comment: I think you should keep somewhere the URLs you are generating.